# React Native how to navigate to other page using onPress in Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have multiple page in my project, I want to go to other page when I will click on "Hello World One" and "Hello World Two" How can I do that?
Thanks in advance for your support.

Please check the image link for better understanding my question- [image]

```
import React, {  useState } from 'react';
    
import { View, Button, Text, FlatList, Dimensions, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
    
     const data = [
    {id: 'a', value: 'From here Navigate to page one ', },
    {id: 'b', value: 'From here Navigate to page two'},
    {id: 'c', value: 'From here Navigate to page three'},
    {id: 'd', value: 'From here Navigate to page four'},
    {id: 'e', value: 'E'},
    {id: 'f', value: 'F'},
  ];
      const numColumns = 2;
      const size = Dimensions.get('window').width/numColumns;
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        itemContainer: {
          width: size,
          height: size,
        },
        item: {
          flex: 1,
          margin: 3,
          textAlign: "center",
          textAlignVertical:"center",
          backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
        }
      });
      
      const Testing = ({ navigation }) => {
        return (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{item.value}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            numColumns={numColumns} />
        );
      }
    
    
    export default Testing;
```

Comment: What routing/navigation package/library is your app using? What have you tried already? What is the issue? Can you provide a [mcve] of your attempt to effect navigation actions?

Comment: I am using React Native stack navigation. In my question I already mentioned what I am trying to do.
I want to navigate to other page when I click on flatlist data (check the image)

Comment: Ok, saying what you want the code to do and showing us what you tried are two different things. SO isn't a code writing service, we need to see specific code you are trying to use otherwise it's just a guessing game and a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to update your **data array** and add a property **navigateTo** and in this property add the screen name which you want to navigate to.

**Note:**

Use the name which you have use in your navigation code.

```
const data = [
    {id: 'a', value: 'From here Navigate to page one ',navigateTo:"SCREEN_NAME" },
    {id: 'b', value: 'From here Navigate to page two',navigateTo:"SCREEN_NAME"},
    {id: 'c', value: 'From here Navigate to page three',navigateTo:"SCREEN_NAME"},
    {id: 'd', value: 'From here Navigate to page four',navigateTo:"SCREEN_NAME"},
    {id: 'e', value: 'E',navigateTo:"SCREEN_NAME"},
    {id: 'f', value: 'F',navigateTo:"SCREEN_NAME"},
  ];
```

Now update your JSX and add a **TouchableOpacity** and add an onPress event. When its fired simply navigate to that screen.

```
 const Testing = ({ navigation }) => {
        return (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(item.navigateTo)} style={styles.itemContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{item.value}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            numColumns={numColumns} />
        );
      }
```

Comment: Small bug, it should be `navigation.navigate(item.navigateTo)` (unless you extract `navigateTo` as an argument in the arrow function)

Comment: @Nathan I apologize for that I will update my code

Comment: No need to apologize! This is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
      const data = [
        {id: 'a', value: 'ScreenOne', },
        {id: 'b', value: 'ScreenTwo'},
      ];
    renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.value)}>
              <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{item.value}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
 )}
```

make sure you have ScreenOne , ScreenTwo in navigation

```
  <Stack.Screen name="ScreenOne" component={ScreenOne}/>
  <Stack.Screen name="ScreenTwo" component={ScreenTwo}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the div in a `Pressable` (or `TouchableOpacity`, or Button from library, or anything you can press) and adding an `onPress` event;

```
const Testing = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Pressable onPress={() => console.log("I've been pressed. Replace this console log with whatever you're using to switch pages")}>
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.item}>{item.value}</Text>
            </View>
          </Pressable>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        numColumns={numColumns} />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I think your code will work only for one page link, I have multiple page please check the image- https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf3MO.png